# Is there a way to get more points for the Job Board?

Tags: tales-of-xillia-2

I've gotten the first Waymarker, and before the next story point I am doing a whole bunch of new jobs that have showed up on the Job Board. (I can go from Sapstrath Seahaven to I think to Rashugal. I'm in Sherilton now, and it looks like there's a couple more places further ahead I can go.)

A couple of the questions on the board are the Red Text ones, so ignoring the Kitty Collar ones, I have 3 quests that require Bronze Seal rank and I'm on Wooden Medal with still about 29k points before I get Bronze Token. With the remaining jobs I have left and the Monsters Contracts I do know the locations of, there is no way I'll reach Bronze Token. And while I expect more jobs to appear (I got 3 monster ones for the Culmar Trail, but with Sapstrath Deepwood the monster hunting jobs didn't appear all at once and I had to make a couple of revisits), I doubt I am getting to Bronze Seal from just taking on jobs.

So I am wondering **if there is a way to get more points for the Job Board that I might have been missing?** Something I can grind for so I can do these Bronze Seal jobs before I continue with the story?